# Font-face doesn't work for me in FF 10.0.1

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using @font-face on my site: http://timkl.com/blog

I've added this snippet to my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "WebSymbolsRegular";
    src: url("http://www.timkl/fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("http://www.timkl/fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("http://www.timkl.com/fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("http://www.timkl.com/fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("http://www.timkl.com/fonts/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular") format("svg");
    }
```

I've then added this value-pair to various classes and ids:

```
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
```

It works fine in Chrome and Safari, however it isn't working FF 10.0.1 :(

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this is highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I used an absolute path, see this: http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_support_in_Firefox

Found out there was a plethora of Stackoverflow posts about this, but not before I submitted mine :S

Comment: I've noticed this with relative paths before too. It's strange actually sometimes they load and sometimes they don't. Older versions of FF were great, but it seems that with each release support of things gets worse and worse.

Comment: I agree, at one point I was only staying for FireBug - but I pushed myself to switch to Chrome and I'm not going back any time soon.